# PHP intermittently unable to load json.so (PHP 5.4.19 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)

Tags: php, ubuntu-12.04, php-5.4

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and needed PHP 5.4 so I'm using **[Ondřej Surý's](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5)** (php5-oldstable) package.

Both phpinfo and the CLI show that JSON is enabled:

```
#php -i | grep -i json
json
json support => enabled
json version => 1.2.1
```

My application mostly works. But periodically (approx one page refresh in ten) there is a PHP error. This only happens intermittently.

```
 PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/json.so'
 - /usr/lib/php5/20100525+lfs/json.so: cannot open shared object file: 
 No such file or directory "json.so"
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: My comment has nothing to do with you actual problem, it's just that you are talking about using `PHP` as an `Apache`'s module but then you used its `CLI` output to prove the existence of JSON library. These two are not necessary the same (could be completely different versions). I think it would be more precise to use `phpinfo()`'s output to prove that the JSON library is actually loaded.

Comment: @Mehran thanks - both phpinfo and the CLI show JSON as being enabled.

Comment: I'm not sure if you'll find a solution or not and I've got none for you but I just wanted to say that you can always compile the newest version of `Apache` and `PHP` from source. That way you can make sure you are not dealing with someone else's mistakes. This is worth a while, specially since `Apache`'s 2.4 version (which is currently the stable one) has got no repository for `Ubuntu`.

Comment: @Mehran this is not true the `stable` Ubuntu PPA [hosts Apajce 2.4 + PHP5.5](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that possible culprit (as I have answered in email) is that you are loading json extension somewhere from the configuration file.

The JSON extension is compiled in the core for PHP 5.4, so you should not load it by hand.

Please check that you don’t have:

1. `json.ini` somewhere in the `/etc/php5/{mods-available}` left over from previous PHP 5.5 installation
2. you are not loading JSON extension from the mentioned script, e.g. no dl(`json.so`).
3. Make sure you have stopped and started Apache2 (same applies to `php5-fpm`) when changing major versions.  The symptoms might indicate that there was some stuck Apache2 thread with previous PHP from package loaded (that would be PHP 5.5 with `json-c` based JSON extension in this case).

Comment: Thanks. 'grep -R "json.so" /etc/php5/' and 'grep -R "json.so" /var/www/app/' both return nothing. Wouldn't your diagnosis cause the error to show for every page load, and not just intermittently? You are correct though that I did have a previous PHP 5.5 installation.

Comment: @MMacdonald Could you try running: find -L /etc/php5 -name 'json*' (and or find -L /etc/php5 and just checking the files by hand).

Comment: find -L /etc/php5 -name 'json*' also returns nothing. And I've now checked every file in /etc/php5/ by hand for "json" and "json.so", with nothing being present.

Comment: One more thing I have just noticed - the bug is marked with 'PHP Startup' and that means the json.so is loaded from php.ini or apache.ini (php_admin_* options).  Is it possible that some parts of your web are using different php.ini or different apache configuration?  Could you do the: grep -R json.so /etc ? :)

Comment: 'grep -R json.so /etc' returns "Binary file /etc/ld.so.cache matches" (plus some unrelated "no such file or directory warnings").

Comment: With the exception of some stray .htaccess files I have a most typical IT question: Have you tried it turning it off and on? :) (E.g. stopping apache2 and starting it again, and/or starting/stopping php5-fpm is that's what you are using.)

Comment: I did already restart Apache (not using php5-fpm). I'll examine .htaccess files and get back to you.

Comment: And did you restart it or stopped&verified that no server is running and started it again?  The randomness of the issue might indicate there's an some apache2 process that didn't die and still has the PHP 5.5 loaded in memory.

Comment: I now can't reproduce the issue anymore, but I'm not exactly sure what I changed (I was in the middle of configuring SSL, so perhaps restarting Apache again did help). I'll contact you again if the issue does recur. Thanks for your help - I was stuck on this for a few days.

Comment: @MMacdonald I have edited the answer and added the indication to stop&start Apache2.  Please accept the answer if the answer did help you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're saying that the json extension is loaded in `phpinfo()`'s output you could be dealing with a bug. Have you checked if the module file is actually there in the filesystem?

You have the following options:

1. Compile PHP 5.4 from source with Apache 2.4
2. Upgrade to the same [repo's stable version](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5) which will give you PHP 5.5 + Apache 2.4.
3. [Submit a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/~ondrej) with the Ondrej in Ubuntu's PPAs and wait for it to be resolved.

For more information check [the debphp site](http://debphp.org/pages/packages.html).

**Submitting a bug is a must**, since if it is a real one it must be fixed for all users.
You could firstly go with option 2 [if you don't conflict with the Migration guidelines like backward compatibility, deprecated functions, etc.](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.php). SO check it and decide.

It also strongly varies depending on the machine you have to do this with. If it is a critical production server, you may not want to compile of change versions on it. Go file the bug and see what the package maintainers have to say about this.

Also please write a reply here when your problem is resolved. I am quite curious as to what it is and hopefully was. :D

Comment: the module is not in the filesystem. I think this might be because json functionality was moved into the PHP core for this version of PHP (but I'm still trying to find details).

Comment: @MMacdonald yes JSON was moved to the core. So maybe you have some sort of version/patch misshab. Can you try to reinstall?

Comment: I had already tried reinstalling (including php5-common). Perhaps I could try on fresh installation of Ubuntu. I've contacted Ondřej Surý by email because I couldn't see how to submit an issue for a PPA on launchpad.

Answer (score 0):

One point that doesn't diagnose or solve the issue (and seems to refer to PHP 5.5), but *might* help with tracing its root cause:

- This [Debian bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=692613) and [Phil Sturgeon's blog](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2013/08/fud-cracker-php-55-never-lost-json-support) explain that some Linux distributions have chosen to replace the official PHP implementation of [ext/json](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/json) with the drop-in compatible [pecl-json-c](https://github.com/remicollet/pecl-json-c). The rationale was that Douglas Crockford's implementation contains a non-free clause in the license ("The Software shall be used for Good, not Evil"). See also [this blog post](https://liorkaplan.wordpress.com/2013/06/01/bye-bye-non-free-php-json-extension/).

Comment: The replacement doesn't happen until PHP 5.5